# I can't fetch session for a specific user

Tags: php

Good day,

I am sending e-mail with php and I use user's session

for example :

```
$subject_user_name= $_SESSION['User']['User_Name'].' '.$_SESSION['User']['User_Surname'];
$subject_baby_name= $profil['Baby_Name'].' '.$profil['Baby_Surname'];           
$subject = sprintf("%s added first for %s ",$subject_user_name,$subject_baby_name);
```

**Problem** : for everyone `$_SESSION` is working but for one user it is not working, and my mail's subject going like this = " added first for Martin"

I need your help. Maybe it is a browser issue.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing how you are *filling in* the session values. Can you add that information?

Comment: Did you try doing print_r($_SESSION)....!

Comment: Yes I did and it is working fine, I can see User_Name and User_Surname and also I fill session directly from one table, no condition for it.

Comment: do you have looked in the log? maybe the filling code is failing

Comment: I even logged in with the user's password and looked the session data I have and Name and Surname was there, Strange thing is there is no condition but I can't fetch user's session. Maybe it is about browser or operating system ?

Comment: if you are saying your posted here works for everyone else except on user, then it is either a client side issue or, when you say not working, an email server/address issue. you should check your mail log.

Comment: Yes it works for everyone except one user. But the issue is not about sending mail, because I first write on database and then send the mail with cron so I can see what will be send. As you say it might be a client problem. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This user might have cookies disabled or have other tight security measures in place. You can 'catch' this problem by checking if the session keys actually have values, like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['User']['User_Name'])
   && isset($_SESSION['User']['User_Surname'])
   && !empty($_SESSION['User']['User_Name'])
   && !empty($_SESSION['User']['User_Surname'])
) {
    $subject_user_name = $_SESSION['User']['User_Name'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['User']['User_Surname'];
} else {
    $subject_user_name = 'Unknown user';
}
```

Alternatively, you could check for just the first or last name, rather then both.

Comment: Thanks I still couldn't figure out. But I will wait until it happen again, I have seen this problem only for one user. So I will wait if she/he write message from another computer.